# Система для идентификация пользователей

Tags: php, алгоритм, веб-программирование, безопасность, идентификация

Есть lua скрипт который пользователи устанавливают себе на компьютер и используют. Данный скрипт при запуске отправляет https запрос на сервер с некоторыми GET параметрами на сервер к php скрипту. php по этим параметрам понимает кто отправил запрос и возвращает id этого пользователя (ну и также другую необходимую информация).

На словах всё просто, а вот когда дело дошло до реализации появились проблемы.
1 - Исходный код lua скрипта который скачивают пользователи можно очень легко получить, поэтому в нём не должно быть нечего что поможет помочь нагнуть систему.
2 - Некоторые значения по которым можно непосредственно делать определение пользователя могут со временем измениться и это приводит к созданию новых учётных записей что портит статистику.
3 - Злоумышленники могут каким либо образом узнать нужные данные и отправлять их на сервер, тем самым выдавая себя за другого пользователя. Таким образом они могут получить данные которые им не доступны.

Я придумал систему которую опишу ниже.

Придуманная мной система:
У пользователя в скрипте есть ключ №1, а в cookie есть ключ №2.
lua скрипт оправляет запрос к php на сервер с ключём №1.
php скрипт получает ключ №1, из cookie берёт ключ №2 и через REMOTE_ADDR получает ip.
Далее 3 варианта действий php скрипта.

**Ключ №1 не был передан и ключ №2 не найден в cookie:**
Значит пользователь запустил скрипт в 1 раз.
Генерируется 2 ключа, 1 возвращается lua скрипту который сохранит его, а другой записывается в cookie.
Далее в БД создаётся запись с 2 ключами и ip пользователя.
Пользователю присваивается свободный id который тоже возвращается и добавляется в БД.

**Ключ №1 был передан и ключ №2 найден в cookie:**
Запрос является полноценным.
lua скрипту из БД вернётся id пользователя по 2 ключам.
В БД будет добавлен текущий ip если его нет. (Так как значение REMOTE_ADDR у 1 пользователя может меняться в БД добавляются все ip с которых были сделаны полноценные запросы. Они могут пригодиться в будущем.).
Если данный ip уже есть в базе то lua скрипту будет отправлен новый ключ и ключ в cookie будет заменён. Также они будет записаны и в БД тем самым уже по ним будет происходить определение.

**Получен только 1 из 2 ключей:**
Это может произойти если пользователь почистил cookie или удалил файл с ключём у себя на компьютере.
Если ip с которого происходит данный запрос есть в списке прошлых ip'шников которые были добавлены при наличии обоих ключей то второй ключ будет восстановлен и lua скрипту будет возвращён нужный id.

Плюсы которые я заметил:
1 - Так как ключи будут выглядеть как хеш да и в целом система для злоумышленников выглядит достаточно непонятно что повышает её безопасность.
2 - Даже если пользователь удалит файл с ключём или почистит cookie php скрипт всё равно найдёт его и не будет создавать новую запись тем самым не засоряя БД.
3 - Чтобы злоумышленнику выдать себя за другого пользователя нужно заставить его скачать и запустить вирус который сворует ключ из cookie и файла. (тут учитываю то что в REMOTE_ADDR нельзя поместить нужный ip насколько я знаю)
4 - Если ip уже если в БД то оба ключа заменяют что повышает безопасность. (то есть если пользователь запустить хоть раз скрипт до того как злоумышленник попытается что-то сделан то его ключи станут недействительны и это может запутать ещё сильнее)

Минусы которые я заметил:
1 - Всё же можно заставить жертву скачать вирус и украсть оба ключа тем самым если пользователь не перезапустит скрипт тем самым сменив ключи он так сказать будет взломан.
2 - Если пользователь всё же будет взломан то ip злоумышленника запишется в базу и он может отправить повторный запрос тем самым изменить оба ключа и полностью украсть учётную запись у реального пользователя. (но скорее всего реальной пользователь напишет в тех.поддержку куда у него всё пропало и я вручную всё верну на место)

Какие минусы я упустил? Что можно добавить/доработать?

Comment: #Артём тут не спрашивают мнений, здесь вам скорее помогут решить проблему нежели кто то будет мнения свои вам писать.

Comment: Немного изменил содержание, теперь всё как надо. Я буквально только что узнал что тут так не принято.

Comment: А без Lua в целом обойтись разве нельзя? Написав для пользователей именно утилиту, а не скрипт.

Comment: Нет, я не пишу обычную прогу, это как дополнение к игре, альтернатив lua лучше нет да и у них всех таже проблема.